# Mutation not updating state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have my mutation committed, but the user state is not updated instead returns null

I recieve data in mutation
The axios call returns the user, but don't update state

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    getters: {
        getUser: state => {
            return state.user;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, user) {
            let url = domain + "user";
            axios
                .get(url, {
                    params: {
                        uuid: user.uid
                    }
                })
                .then(res => {
                    Vue.set(state, user, res.data)
                      // tried    state.user = res.data

                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setUser(context, user) {
            context.commit('setUser', user);
        }
    }
})
```

What did I do wrong?
Thankyou for helping

Comment: Mutations are not `asynchronous`. You need to do the asynchronous call in your `action` and when it's done and you receive the `user` thencommit that context.

Answer (score 1):

Every asynchronous operations should be done in an actions, mutation should be as simple as it is possible. In this case you should move your logic from mutation to action. Something like this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    getters: {
        getUser: state => {
            return state.user;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, user) {
            Vue.set(state, 'user', user)
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getUser(context, user) {
            let url = domain + "user";
            axios.get(url, {
                params: {
                    uuid: user.uid
                }
            }).then(res => {
                context.commit('setUser', res.data)

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
})
```